# How to add pagination feature SliverList

Tags: flutter

I have loaded some news in my SliverList. I want to make this list dynamic. How to add pagination feature in my below code with SliverList?

```
FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
    future: getNews(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      Widget newsListSliver;

      if(snapshot.hasData){
        newsListSliver = SliverList(

          delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index){
            return new NewsList(latestNews: snapshot.data.elementAt(index),);
          }, childCount: snapshot.data.length),
        );
      }else{
        newsListSliver = SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
      }
      return CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[

          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new TabPanel()),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new UrlButtonPanel()),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new ChatNowAd()),

          newsListSliver
        ],
      );
    },
  )
```

Comment: there is far difference between listview and sliverlist. don't make duplicate without knowing the problem.

Comment: No there's no difference between them. ListView is a sliverlist. Add the ScrollController to your CustomScrollView

Comment: there is no controller in sliverlist.

Comment: You can pass a  ScrollController as parameter to [CustomScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView/CustomScrollView.html). Which leads to the same answer

Comment: Are you satisfied with that answer, or is there truly a need to reopen it?

Comment: I solved my problem with some issues. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It is true that custom scrollview has the scroll controller, however there needs to be some custom logic to determin which sliverlist is currently being served. E.g. I have two datasources A and B and a sliver list for each in a custom scrollview. You will need to determin which datasource has reached the end and which needs the next page call triggered, a little more tricky and I think could do with a nice example.